# Change the askToContinue method so that it requires the user to enter Y, y, N or n

Tags: java

Having a problem getting the program to keep running after an error message has occurred. I have tried using different If/Else or While loops to get it to work but none seem to be giving any luck. The current code posted works until you enter something other than y, Y, n, or N. The error message will keep popping up after even if i enter y, Y, n, or N.

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FutureValueApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Avery Owen

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Future Value Calculator\n");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = "y";
        while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            // get the input from the user
            System.out.println("DATA ENTRY");
            double monthlyInvestment = getDoubleWithinRange(sc,
                    "Enter monthly investment: ", 0, 1000);
            double interestRate = getDoubleWithinRange(sc,
                    "Enter yearly interest rate: ", 0, 30);
            int years = getIntWithinRange(sc,
                    "Enter number of years: ", 0, 100);
            System.out.println();

            // calculate the future value
            double monthlyInterestRate = interestRate / 12 / 100;
            int months = years * 12;
            double futureValue = calculateFutureValue(
                    monthlyInvestment, monthlyInterestRate, months);

            // print the results
            System.out.println("FORMATTED RESULTS");
            printFormattedResults(monthlyInvestment, interestRate, 
                    years, futureValue);

            // see if the user wants to continue
            choice = askToContinue(sc);
        }
    }

    public static double getDoubleWithinRange(Scanner sc, String prompt,
            double min, double max) {
        double d = 0;
        boolean isValid = false;
        while (isValid == false) {
            d = getDouble(sc, prompt);
            if (d <= min) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Error! Number must be greater than " + min + ".");
            } else if (d >= max) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Error! Number must be less than " + max + ".");
            } else {
                isValid = true;
            }
        }
        return d;
    }

    public static double getDouble(Scanner sc, String prompt) {
        double d = 0;
        boolean isValid = false;
        while (isValid == false) {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
                d = sc.nextDouble();
                isValid = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error! Invalid number. Try again.");
            }
            sc.nextLine();  // discard any other data entered on the line
        }
        return d;
    }

    public static int getIntWithinRange(Scanner sc, String prompt,
            int min, int max) {
        int i = 0;
        boolean isValid = false;
        while (isValid == false) {
            i = getInt(sc, prompt);
            if (i <= min) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Error! Number must be greater than " + min + ".");
            } else if (i >= max) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Error! Number must be less than " + max + ".");
            } else {
                isValid = true;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }

    public static int getInt(Scanner sc, String prompt) {
        int i = 0;
        boolean isValid = false;
        while (isValid == false) {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            try {
                i = sc.nextInt();
                isValid = true;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Error! Enter a whole number. Try again.");
            }
            sc.nextLine();  // discard any other data entered on the line
        }
        return i;
    }

    public static double calculateFutureValue(double monthlyInvestment,
            double monthlyInterestRate, int months) {
        double futureValue = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= months; i++) {
            futureValue = (futureValue + monthlyInvestment) * 
                          (1 + monthlyInterestRate);
        }
        return futureValue;
    }

    public static String askToContinue(Scanner sc) {
        System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
        String choice = sc.next();
        while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
        sc.nextLine();  // discard any other data entered on the line
        System.out.println("Error! Enter y or n. Try again.");
        }
        return choice;
    }

    private static void printFormattedResults(double monthlyInvestment,
            double interestRate, int years, double futureValue) {
        // get the currency and percent formatters
        NumberFormat c = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        NumberFormat p = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
        p.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);

        // format the result as a single string
        String results
          = "Monthly investment:   " + c.format(monthlyInvestment) + "\n"
          + "Yearly interest rate: " + p.format(interestRate / 100) + "\n"
          + "Number of years:      " + years + "\n"
          + "Future value:         " + c.format(futureValue) + "\n";

        // print the results
        System.out.println(results);
    }
}
```

Comment: you're never updating `choice` var in your `while` loop ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  public static String askToContinue(Scanner sc) {
        System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
        String choice = sc.next();
        while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
        sc.nextLine();  // discard any other data entered on the line
        System.out.println("Error! Enter y or n. Try again.");
        System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): "); //this was missing
        choice = sc.next(); //take the input again
        }
        return choice;
    }
```

You are getting stuck in a while loop in case of invalid input and not accepting the input again.